# Why I can't get google map V2 working

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I can't load the basic google map v2 in my phone.
I do the coding according to this [Website](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api) and i got my api key.
but the program still didn't work.this give the below error

**error**

```
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemap/com.example.googlemap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:235)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1663)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at com.example.googlemap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     ... 11 more
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.googlemap-1.apk]
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
07-22 13:02:24.630: E/AndroidRuntime(5323):     ... 20 more
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<permission android:name = "com.examaple.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name ="com.example.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyAc8wx3VIrczUu7yG6XL1P5rFHLpz3Do2Q"/>



        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Layout :- activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <fragment
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_below="@+id/header"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your xml code your activity code

Comment: Try extending  **FragmentActivity** instead of Activity

Comment: Hi, I tried, but it still didn't work out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your min sdk in 8. You should use `SupportMapFragment`

```
<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:id="@+id/map"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Your activity must extend `FragmentActivity`.

Make sure you have added support library

Also make sure you imported the below

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

Make sure you have referenced the google play services library project.

You can download it from the sdk manager and follow the suggestion in the below link.

[Importing google-play-service library showing a red X next to this reference android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611017/importing-google-play-service-library-showing-a-red-x-next-to-this-reference-and/17611095#17611095)

As a side note if you have updated ADT to rev 22 make sure you check Android private libraries in oerder export tab of java build path.Clean and build. Ignore this if not required.

Also make sure you have enabled google maps for android in the services tab of gogle api console.

Comment: could you help me with this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781578/google-map-v2-button-couldnt-load