# Google Map V2 button couldn't load

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I'm trying to add this button in the Google map.
Upon on click,it will show the location of the place.
However, when I run it, it gave me a force close error.

The button that I would make it work now is "CITY"
The other 2 of the button  ,I've yet to set it.

Here is my logcat error.

```
07-22 14:50:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(11261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 14:50:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(11261): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.googlemap.MainActivity.getFragmentManager
07-22 14:50:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(11261):    at com.example.googlemap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
07-22 14:50:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(11261):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
07-22 14:50:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(11261):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
07-22 14:50:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(11261):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
07-22 14:50:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(11261):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-22 14:50:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(11261):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
07-22 14:50:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(11261):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 14:50:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(11261):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-22 14:50:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(11261):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
07-22 14:50:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(11261):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 14:50:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(11261):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-22 14:50:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(11261):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
07-22 14:50:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(11261):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
07-22 14:50:19.260: E/AndroidRuntime(11261):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my coding.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends  FragmentActivity  {

    private final LatLng LOCATION_BURNABY = new LatLng(49.27645, -122.917587);
    private final LatLng LOCATION_SURREY = new LatLng(49.187500, -122.849000);

    private GoogleMap map;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }

    public void onClick_City(View v){
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LOCATION_BURNABY);
        map.animateCamera(update);
    }

    public void onClick_Burnaby(View v){

    }

    public void onClick_Surrey(View v){

    }
}
```

Comment: What sdk are you running your code on?

Comment: minsdk = "8"..is it that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
map = fm.getMap();
```

Comment: Any idea what does this mean?

[2013-07-22 16:31:47 - googlemap] Failed to install googlemap.apk on device '1427908188A5BBC2E5921E3A219736E': Too many open files
[2013-07-22 16:31:47 - googlemap] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Too many open files
[2013-07-22 16:31:47 - googlemap] Launch canceled!

Comment: @Febbie try to test it on your device.

Comment: I tried on my device and it show me that..
I reboot my eclipse and phone now.
hopefully no more problems

Comment: @Febbie i have not encountered that problem. suggest you check google play services apk availability before testing it on emulator or device. make sure you use google api's

Comment: Hi, I've solve the problem.
i guess something wrong with my phone.
Thanks