# Runtime Error in MapsDemo Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I'm using [this tutorial from Google for MapsActivity](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#adding_the_api_key_to_your_application) but for some reason I have not been getting the required output, the application crashes.

Here is the code I'm using:

1. Manifest.xml

   ```
   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="15"
       android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.ajinkya.samplemapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

   <permission
       android:name="com.ajinkya.samplemapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
       android:protectionLevel="signature" />

   <uses-feature
       android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
       android:required="true" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name="com.ajinkya.samplemapsdemo.MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>

       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="blahblahblahkey" />
   </application>
   ```
2. main.xml

   ```
   <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/map"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
   ```
3. MainActivity.java

   ```
    package com.ajinkya.samplemapsdemo;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

     }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return true;
   }}
   ```

According to Google, a map should be displayed, which is not happening. It gives me the message:

```
Unfortunately, samplemapsdemo has stopped.
```

Here is the log:

```
08-01 18:30:21.671: D/ActivityThread(10657): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
08-01 18:30:21.671: D/ActivityThread(10657): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
08-01 18:30:21.671: D/ActivityThread(10657): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
08-01 18:30:21.741: W/dalvikvm(10657): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a9f390)
08-01 18:31:36.581: D/ActivityThread(10705): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
08-01 18:31:36.581: D/ActivityThread(10705): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
08-01 18:31:36.591: D/ActivityThread(10705): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
08-01 18:31:36.801: W/dalvikvm(10705): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a9f390)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ajinkya.samplemapsdemo/com.ajinkya.samplemapsdemo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1959)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1984)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1150)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4456)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at com.ajinkya.samplemapsdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1923)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    ... 11 more
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:581)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:549)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4235)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    ... 21 more
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:571)
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705):    ... 24 more
```

I believe that this line may be the root cause of all of the problems:

```
08-01 18:31:36.831: E/AndroidRuntime(10705): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you referenced the google pla services library project. also have you enabled maps for android in google api console?

Comment: i(Shift not working) obtained the key via google api console, so that key is enabled, but the thing is :::: How to reference the google play services library project ? Because i (Shift not working :D ) have installed the google play services through Android SDK

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611017/importing-google-play-service-library-showing-a-red-x-next-to-this-reference-and/17611095#17611095. fist reference the library project as suggestd in the link then goto the google api console and enable maps for android as suggested in the docs

Comment: did the referencing part, and enabled maps for android v2 via google api console, but get an "Android library projects cannot be launched" error when  try to run the application

Comment: why are you launching library project you should launch your androi map project. library project is only for referencing

Comment: after adding the library as you said, I launched the main project , but got that error :X

Comment: looks like its a broken link redo the steps and make sure you do it right. if you do it right i don't see any reason why it won't work. Also this is leading to a discussion. if you have further doubts as a new question