# Exception "inflating class fragment"

Tags: android, google-maps

Getting run time exception as "inflating class fragment" when I tried to add Google map in my android application. I go through all the previous comments similar to which I have posted. But I couldn't solve it. 
Log file is attached here

```
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newapp/com.example.newapp.NewApp}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at com.example.newapp.NewApp.onCreate(NewApp.java:12)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     ... 11 more
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:409)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:277)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     ... 21 more
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.newapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.newapp-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:399)
08-07 05:30:41.587: E/AndroidRuntime(2574):     ... 24 more
08-07 05:30:47.677: I/Process(2574): Sending signal. PID: 2574 SIG: 9
08-07 05:30:53.767: D/AndroidRuntime(2650): Shutting down VM
08-07 05:30:53.767: W/dalvikvm(2650): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newapp/com.example.newapp.NewApp}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at com.example.newapp.NewApp.onCreate(NewApp.java:12)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     ... 11 more
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:409)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:277)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     ... 21 more
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.newapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.newapp-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:399)
08-07 05:30:53.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2650):     ... 24 more
08-07 05:30:56.837: I/Process(2650): Sending signal. PID: 2650 SIG: 9
```

manifest.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.newapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="********************************" />
       <permission
        android:name="com.venky.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.newapp.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.newapp.NewApp"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
           </application>

</manifest>
```

and the java file NewApp.java

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class NewApp extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_app);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_app, menu);
        return true;
    }
    }
```

activity_new_app.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".NewApp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you please provide the activity_new_app.xml ?

Comment: post your xml layout also.

Comment: Have you referenced google play services library project in your android map project?

Comment: @Vegolath, xml file included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One visible mistake

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Your meta tag must be a child of application tag in manifest

```
     <meta-data   // should be inside application tag.
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="********************************" />
```

Change this

```
     <permission
    android:name="com.venky.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

to

```
    <permission
    android:name="com.example.newapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Comment: @Raghunaadan,I updated the file but the exception remains there.

Comment: @maria have you referenced google play services library project in your android map project.

Comment: @Raghunaadan, I have added google play services library to my project workspace. Did you mean the same?

Comment: @maria not workspace yes you need to import your google play services into workspa e in to eclipse but you alos need to reference the same in your android map project.

Comment: @Raghunaadan, how can I reference? Sorry I am a new comer in this field, that's why I ask doubts about these basic things.

Comment: @maria follow the steps @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611017/importing-google-play-service-library-showing-a-red-x-next-to-this-reference-and/17611095#17611095