# google-play-services won't build into Android Maps HelloWorld project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, eclipse-adt

**UPDATE:** A UI bug was preventing me from importing google-play-services_lib. I had to click immediately below the SDK list to be able to scroll to see the Library box. See [the image in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611017/importing-google-play-service-library-showing-a-red-x-next-to-this-reference-and) for more info.

I am using Android IDE to get a Hello World map app, which I have named Intactless2. The files are all named correctly, android-support-v4.jar in /libs, I have a valid API key, etc.

I followed Google's Android Maps guide, copying and pasting the Java and activity_main.xml verbatim:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

I correctly added everything there to my manifest. I got an error on `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"`... 's value being incorrect, so I hardcoded the integer from the version.xml file so that it's `android:value="4030500"`. Otherwise my manifest is unchanged.

I tried all of the solutions in the top Google hits for the error messages I'm getting and it still won't run. Normally, this would indicate an idiosyncratic bug that I haven't thought about that might even be unrelated to Google Play Services, but I rebuilt it exactly as Google's guide suggests and redid all of the recommendations in those posts and still can't use Google Play Services.

I am running a 4.4 emulator and 4.4 is the minimum version my project will build to. I have tried the following to be able to use google-play-services/google-play-services_lib in my app:

1) Made an Eclipse project for Google Play Services and added it to my project. Right-click on my project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects Add -> google-play-services_lib.
    a) Checked google-play-services_lib in Order & Export
    b) Unchecked oogle-play-services_lib in Order and Export
2) Copy-pasted google-play-services, google-play-services_lib, and google-play-services.properties from my Android SDK directory to my /libs directory in my project.

1) Properties -> Android -> Target Build Path -> Android 4.4
2) Properties -> Android -> Target Build Path -> Google APIs (the one directly below "Android 4.4)

That's a lot of combinations including the solutions people on StackOverflow have suggested.

Also, if I add `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps" />` (or remove the gms as some guides advise) to my manifest, I get this LogCat error:

`11-13 00:57:18.890: E/PackageManager(938): Package com.example.intactless2 requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.gms.maps; failing!`

**Importing google-play-services/google-play-services_lib as an Eclipse project:**

Screenshot of google-play-services_lib Eclipse project: http://postimg.org/image/ukbqjk9lp/

Screenshot of my hello world Maps project in Package Explorer: http://postimg.org/image/589t2137h/

Console output:

```
...
[2013-11-12 21:57:13 - Intactless2] Installing Intactless2.apk...
[2013-11-12 21:57:19 - Intactless2] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2013-11-12 21:57:19 - Intactless2] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-11-12 21:57:19 - Intactless2] Launch canceled!
```

LogCat:

```
11-13 01:03:44.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1886): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 01:03:44.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1886): Process: com.example.intactless2, PID: 1886
11-13 01:03:44.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1886): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.intactless2/com.example.intactless2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
11-13 01:03:44.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-13 01:03:44.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-13 01:03:44.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
...
```

**Putting google-play-services.jar, google-play-services_lib.jar, and google-play-services.jar.properties directly into my project's /libs directory**

Screenshot of my hello world Maps project in Package Explorer: http://postimg.org/image/l68z4crl7/

Console output:

```
...
[2013-11-12 22:15:20 - Intactless2] Uploading Intactless2.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-11-12 22:15:20 - Intactless2] Installing Intactless2.apk...
[2013-11-12 22:15:37 - Intactless2] Success!
[2013-11-12 22:15:37 - Intactless2] Starting activity com.example.intactless2.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2013-11-12 22:15:41 - Intactless2] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.intactless2/.MainActivity }
```

LogCat:

```
11-13 01:15:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1959): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 01:15:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1959): Process: com.example.intactless2, PID: 1959
11-13 01:15:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1959): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
11-13 01:15:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
11-13 01:15:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-13 01:15:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4784)
11-13 01:15:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
11-13 01:15:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
11-13 01:15:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
11-13 01:15:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
11-13 01:15:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
11-13 01:15:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
11-13 01:15:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at com.example.intactless2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
11-13 01:15:43.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1959):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
```

Thank you in advance! Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: did you reference the library project or add it as jar?

Comment: I did both and posted the logs for both. Neither worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611017/importing-google-play-service-library-showing-a-red-x-next-to-this-reference-and. check this if it helps

Comment: @Raghunandan I wasn't copying the google-play-services_lib into my workspace but it didn't work when I did. I ran it twice, once with google-play-services_lib checked in Order and Export and once unchecked. I cleaned my project before each run. My logs (they were the same in both runs) are here: http://pastebin.com/jgP0hxbJ

Comment: what is not working? `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable` usually happens if you do not reference the library project properly

Comment: I think it's because google-play-services_lib is set up incorrectly too. Can you look at these screenshots? http://postimg.org/image/ukbqjk9lp/ and http://postimg.org/image/589t2137h/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41073/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-janegoodall)

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for all your help. A UI bug was preventing me from importing google-play-services_lib into Intactless2 (my map project) as a library file. I had to click immediately below the SDK list to be able to scroll to see the Library box.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you are using a 4.4 emulator - you need to use the `Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 19` emulator to test with Google Play Services.

Comment: i believe this `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable` usually happens if you don't reference the library project properly

Answer (score 0):

I Think You have error in you XML file ,because in log-cat you are getting

```
 Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment first you try to rectify it
```