# Google+ Locations

Tags: api, location, google-plus

Now that the Google latitude API is gone is there a way to get to the Google+ locations data? I wanted to do some scripting based on the location of my phone but I don't see a way in their API documentation. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location of your phone with the `google-play-services` SDK for Android. You'll need to set up a `google-play-services_lib` project in Eclipse *as a library project* and then import that project into your location app as a library.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Unfortunately getting `google-play-services` to work in Eclipse isn't that straight-forward and the error messages aren't very informative. If you have trouble setting up the library, read this:

[Importing google-play-service library showing a red X next to this reference android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611017/importing-google-play-service-library-showing-a-red-x-next-to-this-reference-and)

Once it's working in Eclipse, you can use google-play-services to get your GPS coordinates:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html
http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary.html

I haven't tried this and it's a few years old. It might be better for what you're doing, since you won't have to deal with setting up Google Play Services:

http://webdesignergeeks.com/mobile/android/geting-current-location-in-android-application-using-gps/