# Google Map API code is not working. please help me

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

}
```

Manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.map.googlemapv2"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

        <permission
            android:name="com.map.googlemapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <!--
         The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
        -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission   android:name="com.map.googlemapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.map.googlemapv2.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
        </application>

    </manifest>

Layout File

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnSurrey" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

StackTrace :

```
        12-12 06:19:45.460: D/AndroidRuntime(907): Shutting down VM
        12-12 06:19:45.460: W/dalvikvm(907): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4aeab90)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907): Process: com.amaps.androidmap, PID: 907
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amaps.androidmap/com.amaps.androidmap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.amaps.androidmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  ... 11 more
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4777)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  ... 20 more
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.amaps.androidmap-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.amaps.androidmap-2, /system/lib]]
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
        12-12 06:19:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  ... 23 more
        12-12 06:23:20.842: I/Process(907): Sending signal. PID: 907 SIG: 9
        12-12 06:44:02.832: D/AndroidRuntime(1054): Shutting down VM
        12-12 06:44:02.832: W/dalvikvm(1054): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4aeab90)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054): Process: com.amaps.androidmap, PID: 1054
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amaps.androidmap/com.amaps.androidmap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at com.amaps.androidmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     ... 11 more
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4777)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     ... 21 more
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.amaps.androidmap-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.amaps.androidmap-1, /system/lib]]
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
        12-12 06:44:02.852: E/AndroidRuntime(1054):     ... 24 more
        12-12 06:49:03.212: I/Process(1054): Sending signal. PID: 1054 SIG: 9
        12-12 06:58:53.742: D/AndroidRuntime(1100): Shutting down VM
        12-12 06:58:53.742: W/dalvikvm(1100): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4aeab90)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100): Process: com.amaps.androidmap, PID: 1100
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amaps.androidmap/com.amaps.androidmap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at com.amaps.androidmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     ... 11 more
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4777)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     ... 21 more
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.amaps.androidmap-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.amaps.androidmap-2, /system/lib]]
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
        12-12 06:58:53.762: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     ... 24 more
        12-12 06:59:41.712: I/Process(1100): Sending signal. PID: 1100 SIG: 9
```

i import the library from path :
adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject//google-play-services_lib/
 i also made the reference but still nothing happen.Dont knw what to do.

Comment: post your xml code: error is within your xml code.

Comment: have you referenced google play services library project in your android map project??

Comment: error occur while loading the xml layout. if i remove the fragment with simple textview it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have not referenced to the google play services library project properly. Make sure you do that first.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

Your min sdk is 8. Use `SupportMapFragment`  and extend `FragmentActivity` and use support library.

or change to api level to 12 and above.

You are also missing

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

in Application Tag of manifest

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Make sure you have referenced google play services library project properly and followed all the steps in the above link

Comment: error occur while loading the xml layout. if i remove the fragment with simple textview it works fine.

Comment: @user3095303 have you referenced google play servicess library project?

Comment: @user3095303 i don't think so. pls post how you have referenced the library project by editing your post

Comment: here is the library path:-                                     adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject//google-play-services_lib/

Comment: @MSJohn follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611017/importing-google-play-service-library-showing-a-red-x-next-to-this-reference-and fro referring library project. Then clean and build. See if you get Exception again.

Comment: sir i followed your instructions but again same problem.

Comment: @MSJohn right click on your project goto properties . Choose Android. See if your library project is referenced and has a green tick. If you solve your referencing problem then you will not get that exception.

Comment: Sir i checked it.
its green.

Comment: @MSJohn this all i can do to help. Sorry.

Comment: its ok Raghu sir,Thank u very much :)

Comment: sir last thing i want to ask is it work fine without API key.
if i use "@integer/google_play_services_version" instead of API key

Comment: there is no need of API key?

Comment: @MSJohn you absolutely need api key edited my previous comment

Comment: <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
i use my API key in value place 
"AIzaSyBdMo52LgNjZvbtLRoY_xXXXXXXXXXXXX"
.

Comment: @MSJohn pls follow https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2 instead of asking fro everything. Still have a doubt ask a new question. Questions cannot be answered in comments. pls post a new thread

Comment: sir its al-most done but now only show map zoomin zoom out button, donot load the map

Comment: @MSJohn 1. check if you have the right key. re-generate the key if not. 2. Enable maps for android in the google api console. 3. mak sure you test on a device that has google play services apk installed. 4. still got a problem ask a new question. I won't be commenting on this post any further.

Answer (score 0):

Replace it:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSurrey" />
```

with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

add this in maifest:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

I also use the this code. and change the xml layout also bt still the same problem occur. please post me the correct code. is this code working on android 4.4 coz whem i am running this code it display the message that no compatible target is found.

the main problem occur while loading the map fragment.(XML layout)

Answer (score 0):

Your MapFragment should be defined like this.

```
 <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```