# AdRequest.Builder cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, admob

I'm incorporating AdMob into my app. I've followed the steps in the developers page. However AdRequest.Builder() is being underlined with red and it says:

> AdRequest cannot be resolved to a type

and

> AdRequest.Builder cannot be resolved to a type.

What could be the problem?

```
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;


public class FireRoomActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fire_room);

        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();   
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

In xml I've shown admob as such:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="bla bla"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your code is mix for [Admob SDK (Google Play)](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play) and [Android (6.4.1 and earlier SDKs)](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#android)

Use

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

and

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="bla bla"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

if you use Admob SDK (Google Play)

Or use

```
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
```

and

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="bla bla"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

if you use earlies SDK

For Admob SDK (Google Play) not forget to change namespase

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: thanks. What's the difference between Admob SDK (Google Play) and the second SDK? which one is preferable for Android game app?

Comment: Admob SDK (Google Play) is newest SDK and use "built-in" Google Play services. I preffered use newest SDK.

Comment: The namespace should be xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" instead.

Comment: hey dude if i chose the solution 2 what the manifest code should be ??

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();   
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);           
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**Note:**

1. Make sure you have included the necessary `library` in your `project` and **permissions** in your `manifest`.
2. Also check whether you have given correct `ad-mob` id in your **xml**.

**EDIT :**

To add test device, you could try

```
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);  //for emulators
adRequest.addTestDevice("device_id");              //for real device, enter device id
```

Comment: it of course works. But I'll need later to test on the phone like: 
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
    .addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4")  // My Galaxy Nexus test phone
    .build();

But it will give me an error.

Comment: Generally, the documentation says: "Before being passed to AdView.loadAd, an AdRequest may be customized using an AdRequest.Builder to allow Google to better target ads.
"
In the xml I did this, which is just copy paste from the documentation:     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="bla bla"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

Comment: I've included library, otherwise the rest of the code would be underlined. And yes I've added network permissions in the AndroidManifest

Comment: @Nazerke Even if you run this code alone, you will get test ads in emulator and testing device. once if the app is uploaded in playstore the app will receive real ads.

Comment: @Nazerke check my edit.. add those lines before `adView.loadAd(adRequest)`

Comment: Thanks, it is a workaround. I'm giving an upvote for a workaround, can't accept it as an answer because it doesn't answer why I'm getting the exception.

Comment: @Nazerke k no probz:)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are encountering Library Reference Bug of `Eclips`. Which returns this Types of error on following developers page's Steps.

Go To your Project Properties and Click on Android Tab.
[image]

Check, if a `Red`cross mark exists.

if yes, you are encountering it for sure.

Eclipse does weird things when importing an existing project (google-play-services-lib), especially if you try to import and then allow the project to be automatically 'copied' to your workspace.

[To Solve this,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611017/importing-google-play-service-library-showing-a-red-x-next-to-this-reference-and)

> 1. Erase all google-play-services projects from your workspace.
> 2. Close Eclipse.
> 3. Manually copy the google-play-services-lib folder (....sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib) into your workspace.
> 4. Open Eclipse

Now add the `Library From your workspace as existing project` instead of

```
....sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib
```

At last, add project reference library from project properties as you did before.

> Remember, directions on developers page is fully perfect without this single bug. So, Follow All other directions As the Page says.