# AdMob Ads Not Displaying in Real Device

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

Hey Guys I am using "Google Play Services" to integrate AdMobs banners ads in my application. In Eclips the ads looks fine but when I try to run the application it doesn't show ads in real device. Here is the XML Code I am using for ads.

I am not using any Java code for ads. Just using this XML code provided here. (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/play-migration)

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
      android:id="@+id/adView"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5278017493272368/8871679336"/>
```

Here is the Screenshot of the ads showing in Eclips.

[image: Ads In Eclips are displayed Like this]

Please help me to solve this problem. Any Help will be Appreciated.

Thanls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load it.

Try adding xmlns attribute.

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/adView"
  ads:adSize="BANNER"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5278017493272368/8871679336"/>
```

in onCreate event add this code:

```
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: added this in code, but now getting error in Main ACtivity. 1-AdRequest.Builder cannot be resolved to a type. 2- The method loadAd(AdRequest) in the type AdView is not applicable for the arguments (AdRequest) NOw what do you say?

Comment: Using the search function I got this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607746/adrequest-builder-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type