# com.google.android.gms. No completion available

Tags: android, google-api, google-maps-api-2

Im trying to create my first Google Map app and so i'm following this tutorial: 
[check_Tutorial](http://codebybrian.com/2012/12/06/google_maps_android_v2_sample.html) there you will see the following imports:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

My problem is when i get to this point i can not add these imports because when i type them they don't appear as if they even exist!! so that's why i can not continue with my map and i've tried so many times with other tutorials they always appear in order the maps works...

If you know the reason why i can not add these imports please let me know 'cause is driving me crazy!!

Error adding the library!
I forgot to tell you that i receive this image a couple of sec after having added the google play services library:
[image: ver imagen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason not import(package) google map library in your project
1)You are not selected Android build Target as google API
                ->Your project right click properties select as google apis
2)You are not added google play service lib in your project(as Is Library)
         ->Your project right click properties select as google apis.

Install in your device-
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms

Comment: I guess you are right. So i did as you said: i click on properties and added the library and click apply and selected android build target as google api. But then when i come back to check it, i get the following (check the new image i  just download to my original question please!)

Comment: I think google play service lib is not same eclipse workspace. so you have to import google play service lib in import option (Checkbox Copy project in workspace.. Importing option )

Comment: Thanks a lot man!! man i love you!! i have been trying to figured that problem out! gracias papito!! en seiro!! ypu 've save my life and my grade!! it works!!

Answer (score 1):

Please install [Google Play Service](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms) in your device from Google play store.

and also include libraries in your project.

In Eclipse:
File->Import-> Android-> Existing Android Code into Workspace->Browse-> adt->sdk->extras->google->google_play_services->lib Project.

Click OK,
Remember to check option to import libs into workspace.

add the libraries to the project. Clean the Project and Run.

Comment: Thank u very much for replying so quickly but i omitted to write that i had added that library already. But thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference google play services library project in your android project.

Follow the steps @

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

If using eclipse IDE check this

[Importing google-play-service library showing a red X next to this reference android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611017/importing-google-play-service-library-showing-a-red-x-next-to-this-reference-and)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge but i had added that libray already but thanks man!! (Y)

Comment: @Alejo_Blue my second link is no different from the accepted answer. as you posted its a broken link path hence the red x you see. the second link tell you exactly how to fix it.

Comment: Yeah you're right Raghunandan, but i didn't noticed you had posted that link i guess it's cause it's posted after the accepted answer... thanks a lot man anyway!!

Comment: @Alejo_Blue nope i posted it long before anyone answered. You din't notice it. I posted it even before you posted the snap shot.