# Android: Google Map V2 not working as expected using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I'm integrating google map v2 to my android app, I'm using Eclipse with minimum SDK Version version 10. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Ace as a test device.

I've read and done the necessary steps in this site:

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

I've also consult this tutorials:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

The problem is that the google-play-service_lib seems to be not included although I have done the step Project > Properties > Android > Add: google-play-service_lib

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I've tried solving this problem by doing Project > Properties > Java Build Path and adding the google-play-service_lib, but this will cause a runtime error java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable

Has anyone encounter this problem, and how did you solve this?

[image: Project > Properties > Java Build Path]

Comment: Must sure you are using updated Google Play lib service?

Comment: Yep, I've update all to what's current right now

Comment: Are you getting green mark when add it to as a library project?

Comment: Whenever I add the library project, it is green. But when I visit the Project > Properties > Android part again, it will be red. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: @Marl copy the library project to the folder where your project is then try to reference the same. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611017/importing-google-play-service-library-showing-a-red-x-next-to-this-reference-and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your project code and `google-play-service_lib`'s code are at same place otherwise it will keep fireing import error.

Answer (score 1):

[image]The problem is because when you are importing lib project at that time you haven't copy that project in to workspace.

So finally when import it enable "**Copy to Workspace**" checkbox.

And after that give a reference to your project like below image.

Answer (score 1):

As you said

**I add the library project, it is green. But when I visit the Project > Properties > Android part again, it will be red.**

Just copy your project into your workspace or if its already copied into the workspace make sure you have also copied your `Google-play-services library` into your workspace otherwise it will always give you library error as it will not get the library available into your workspace.