# googlemap class in googlemapv2

Tags: android, google-maps

i am currently working with googlemap v2. the problem is that i can't use the class "googlemap" it shows an error. i am using google api 4.2. how can i use this class. xml file code is given below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Which error? Did you add the Google Play Services library to your project?

Comment: Can you Specify the error??

Comment: i can't use the class Googlemap in my activity

Comment: @user1057197 Have you referenced GooglePlay Services??

Comment: yes i am using the googleplay services

Comment: @user1057197 i don't think you are. Hence the error.
    `import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;`

Comment: @user1057197 and post the code that has error ie Activity class

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Then you have to use the SupportMapFragment class in your activities.
Example:

```
SupportMapFragment mapa;
mapa = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Because the error would pop if he tries to cast the class in the activity (as he says it happens in the activity). It happened to me last week. It may not be the reason but i cant post comments on other people's posts =/

Comment: You're right, he says he can't use the class especifically, not get the fragment. I missread. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference GooglePlay services in your android project and import

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap

You can follow

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

and Reference

[Importing google-play-service library showing a red X next to this reference android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611017/importing-google-play-service-library-showing-a-red-x-next-to-this-reference-and)