# Unable to add library to android project

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to add google play services library to my project. I follow the procedure of adding a library correctly. After adding it properly when I next time check library section in properties it shows red cross in front of added library. I have attached the screenshot also. Any help please?

[image]

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611017/importing-google-play-service-library-showing-a-red-x-next-to-this-reference-and

Comment: Make sure host project and library project are in same workspace.

Comment: remove the previous library first and add again and select ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that the libraries and the project are at the same place, i.e.

1. Copy the libraries in the same folder as your project
2. Import the libraries (file > Import > Existing Project in workspace)
3. Open properties of library > Android and select Is Library
4. Open project properties > Android > Add (library)
5. LSelect the library
6. save the properties

If this does not work for you copy the jar files from its lib folder and paste it in the projects lib. This should only be done if the above method doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If project name or path changed,

1. Select item (red cross marked library project)
2. Remove.
3. Add again.