# material support library, can't find Cardview/Recycleview

Tags: android, eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-cardview

I have searched the internet but i couldn't find my answer. How can I use Card view/Recycle view they are not in my layout palette or i can't use them manually and I am using eclipse

Answer (score 9):

The `CardView` and `RecycleView` are not by default in the `AppCompat` library. You should include the CardView and RecycleView libraries manual to your project.

*Reference:* https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#Dependencies

**Gradle (using Android Studio):**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to add them manually can you give me more details  @Rolf

Comment: Do you use Eclipse or Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

In the layout palette there is a section called "Custom" click on the "CustomView" and you shall see all the imported views from the dependencies added in the gradle file.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

my problem when adding the library was the same as this guys problem

[Unable to add library to android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525295/unable-to-add-library-to-android-project)

so I fixed it.