# Error on layout fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I Create google map application

my layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" >
</fragment>
```

Code is

```
 map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
```

StackTrace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.androiddev.googlemap/ir.androiddev.googlemap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
0at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
at ir.androiddev.googlemap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/ir.androiddev.googlemap-1.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
```

and my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ir.androiddev.googlemap"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<permission
    android:name="ir.androiddev.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="ir.androiddev.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="ir.androiddev.googlemap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="My-API-key" />

</manifest>
```

and Code is

```
package ir.androiddev.googlemap;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(35.724543, 51.407633);
private GoogleMap googleMap;
private GoogleMap map;
// latitude and longitude
double latitude = 35.724543;
double longitude = 51.407633;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

    Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(HAMBURG)
            .title("Dana Ravesh")
            .snippet("Tehran ...")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
}

private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Dana Ravesh ");

        // adding marker
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Post your  `manifest.xml ` file

Comment: @SimplePlan I post that

Comment: getFragmentManager() is only supported above sdk 11 version..

Comment: You have to make many changes to run your this app do as @Raghunandan answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your min sdk is 8

You need to use SupportMapFragment

```
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

Also change

```
  map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)) .getMap();
```

Make sure you extend `FragmentActivity`

Also make sure you have referenced google play services library project in your android project.

Also add this as a child of application tag in manifest

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: also add suggestion for `<meta-data> (version) tag` that might be find error in future.

Comment: but when I put your code ,show this error SupportMapFragment cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @SaeedHashemi import from the support library. also have you referenced google play services

Comment: @Raghunandan How I do this?

Comment: @SaeedHashemi first make sure you have referenced google play serives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611017/importing-google-play-service-library-showing-a-red-x-next-to-this-reference-and. Second you need to import `SupportMapFragment`.

Comment: @Raghunandan First I import that,Can I create map view without fragment?

Comment: @SaeedHashemi no i don't know the other way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50946/discussion-between-saeed-hashemi-and-raghunandan)