# I'm getting "Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at value with value @integer/google_play_services_version)"

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-services, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app on Ionic Framework/cordova, and when I try "cordova run android" I get this:

> "Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at value with
> value  @integer/google_play_services_version)"

I don't really know what is happening, I tried to set the value with a fixed value (I know is not the best solution), and the problem continues.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#install_and_configure_the_google_play_services_sdk

Answer (score 23):

For anyone encountering this issue using Android Studio and/or Gradle, you just need to make sure that you have the right dependency in your grade file. Again, do NOT hardcode this value into a versions.xml file..

Gradle eg.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
}
```

Comment: Building on this answer, you can get Cordova to add this Gradle dependency for you during the build by adding a framework element to your plugin.xml file: <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0" />. I'm using Cordova version 5.1.1 and cordova-android version 4.0.2.

Answer (score 11):

Install and configure the Google Play services SDK properly. You don't need to hard code that value.

- Add Google Play services as an Android library project.

I have found that the play services libproject has to be imported onto the same physical drive as your project. (check the 'Copy projects into workspace' checkbox when you import)

Comment: how do you do that if you are using Unity3d ?

Comment: After you have downloaded the SDK, you can add it as project from here:  [AndroidSdk_Home]/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib .. thanks to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17611095/2162226

Comment: adding the play services libproject to the same physical drive worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

I solved the problem by copying the `version.xml` file from google play service lib.

```
google-play-services_lib/res/values/version.xml
```

to my project

```
MyApp/res/values/version.xml
```

Comment: Helped me too... Thanks !

Comment: this answer is a little bit wrong because when google update it's support library they will update the value of @integer/google_play_services_version and you will have problems in you application. It can be fixed with this answer very easy but fix is temporally

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the play services library to your project. This doesn't work by jus adding an external jar. You need to import the play_services_lib project into your workspace. And then add this library to you project by going to

Your Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library

Checkout this link for detailed explanation on how to import the play_services_lib into your workspace

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

After this the error will vanish and you need not add any fixed value.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone encountering this issue using Android Studio / Gradle, you just need to make sure that you have the right dependency in your grade file.

1. You need to setup Google Play Services – https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup
   (1. Debes configurar Google Play Services)
2. If you already completed previous step then (si ya completaste ese paso entonces)…
   Let say that you have this Gradle:  (suponiendo que ya tienes un archivo Gradle asi:)

   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: ‘libs’, include: [‘*.jar’])
       compile ‘com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0’
   }

you need to add a single line for Gradle to include the Google Play Services library
(solo necesitas agregar un solo renglon para que Gradle incluya la libreria de Google Play Services library)

> dependencies {
>       compile fileTree(dir: ‘libs’, include: [‘*.jar’])
>       compile ‘com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3’
>       compile ‘com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0’ }

Is a bad practice to hardcode this value into the versions.xml file (se considera una mala practica “quemar” o dejar fijo este valor en el archivo mencionado)

Comment: https://maograciag.wordpress.com/2015/10/22/error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name/

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this issue while building in Unity3D:

1.`Assets/PlayServicesResolver/AndroidResolver/ResolveClientJars`

2.Build again

This fixed this exact issue for me today.

```
stderr[
AndroidManifest.xml:19: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version'). 
]
```