# no resource found @integer/google_play_services_version whats this?

Tags: android, metadata, android-manifest, google-play-services

I have to Integrate Inmobi skd into my project I have gone through this https://www.inmobi.com/support/integration/23817448/22051163/android-sdk-integration-guide/ tutorial and when I mentioned 
to androidmenidfest.xml file it gives an error No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/
 google_play_services_version').

to resolve this I have referred this [I'm getting "Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at value with value @integer/google_play_services_version)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923933/im-getting-error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-value-with) tutorial but it doesn't help me..
Please help me I am newbie in android..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Configure google play service lib in your Project properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/19990244/991085

Comment: Giru bhai I have gone through your tutorial but doesn't help....

Comment: post your manifest code

Answer (score 23):

As told by Simple Plan do like:

**In Eclipse:**

Eclipse -> import -> existing android code -> browse -> navigate to google-play-services_lib FOLDER (android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject).

then, select your project--> right click -> properties -> android -> libraries, add -> select the project you just imported -> OK

**UPDATE:**

**In Android Studio:**

Simply add this line to `build.gradle` and click on Sync

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

And also make sure to add this line at end of the build.gradle (I have no clue why putting this at the end (and not at the beginning ) solves the error.)

> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

For more info refer [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) link

Comment: done this and I add library via right Click-->Project--> libraries-->add Libraries -->Google-play-services then it removes R.java file from my build....

Comment: make sure your project and library should have in same workspace

Comment: Be sure to check the box in the which says 'Copy Project into Workspace', otherwise you may hit a privilege error.

Comment: Giving others answer without their reference.

Comment: project--> right click -> properties -> android -> libraries, add -> select the project you just imported  -> How does this path changes with the Android Studio 1.5.1 version.Cant find this path?

Comment: you can add this line to your build.gradle : compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'