# Migrating eclipse project from github to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, migrating, code-migration

I am in the process of migrating my current project from eclipse to studio which is present on github.

My project makes use of google play services lib and an another library (calendar lib to be precise)

I tried many ways of migrating to studio following the tutorials on the net but I am not able to achieve it.

I am getting problem with my Google play service library. The error is cannot find resource @integer/google_play_services_version

At this point of time I confused don't know Wat to do. Can some please tell me proper way of migrating.

It will be of great help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325333/no-resource-found-integer-google-play-services-version-whats-this)

Comment: Thanks but I am not getting any issues in eclipse. I am happily coding in eclipse. I am facing problem when I migrate from eclipse to studio

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718026/how-to-build-an-android-library-with-android-studio-and-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the error in Android Studio? This should not be the case, as Android studio handles libraries through gradle dependancies. You can check your build.gradle for the dependencies. If you are seeing this error, I assume it is in Eclipse, which the link @SurajPalwe13 provided should help fix.

Migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio should be as easy as Importing the Eclipse project into Android Studio.

In Android Studio, File > Import > Select Eclipse project directory. Then a import wizard should come up.

Alternatively, you can export your Eclipse Project to contain gradle files:
In the latest version of Eclipse, Right Click Project > Export > Android > Gradle. Then follow through the export wizard. You should then be able to import the build.gradle file in Android Studio.