# Error while implementing Google Maps Android - SupportMapFragment cannot be resolved as Type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I'm at the beginning of programming android apps and I got this error while I try to implement Google Maps into a fragment. I surfed the web and I saw that is a really common problem but I saw also that all other solutions do not work in my case. I paste below the portion of code with all the imports:

```
public class GeolocalizzazioneFragment extends Fragment {
private final LatLng CENTER_POINT = new LatLng(44.22625, 12.06861);

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_geolocalizzazione, container, false );
        //super.onCreateView(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //ottieni il controllo del fragment su cui caricare la mappa
        GoogleMap map = ((MapSupportFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        //centra la mappa su CENTER_POINT, con zoom 5
        //map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(CENTER_POINT, 5));
        //centra la mappa sulla posizione del device
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        //animazione dello zoom sulla nostra animazione all'apertura
        //Parametri: livello di zoom=10; durata animazione = 1000 millisecondi (1 sec)
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 1000, null);

        try{
            URL url = new URL("### url where I get xml with location marker datas ###");  //prendo l'URL del file XML dal quale prendo i dati dei POI
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();          //instauro la connessione col file XML

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());

            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            for (int i=0; i<nodes.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Element item = (Element) nodes.item(i);
                String name = item.getAttribute("name");
                String address = item.getAttribute("address");
                String stringLat = item.getAttribute("lat");
                String stringLong = item.getAttribute("long");
                String icon = item.getAttribute("icon"); //assigned variable for the XML icon attribute
                Double lat = Double.valueOf(stringLat);
                Double lon = Double.valueOf(stringLong);

                // map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                // map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(lat,lon))
                                .title(name)
                                .snippet(address)
                );
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    }
```

I also checked that in "Java Build Path" window "Android private libraries" are correctly checked and as you can see I already imported "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;" and I also imported the "google-play-services.jar" library.
And my error is at the line below:

```
GoogleMap map = ((MapSupportFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

If you need other portions of code, just ask and I will paste :)

P.S.: My IDE is Eclipse.

Comment: Is error in this line *GoogleMap map = ((MapSupportFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();* ?

Comment: exactly that line.. @maven

Comment: Perhaps you are missing the import statement for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.

Comment: No..I imported it, but I think that I solved dividing that code (after 2 hours of attempts). I written this and there are no more errors for SupportMapFragment:

      MapFragment map =((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));

         GoogleMap mappa = map.getMap();

But now, when I run into my Galaxy note 2, the app crash before start :/

Comment: you need to import support jar also

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps, maybe you missed some:

- Copy google play service lib into your lib folder
- Copy android supported v4 lib in your lib folder
- Add google play service lib and android supported v4 to your build path
- import google play service project into your workspace select your
  project and right click>properties>android>add project lib(the
  google play service) and do not tick "is library"
- Select the google play service project and right click and go to
  properties>android>tick "is lib"
- Use FragmentActivity and use Support to use supported libs.
- Clean and rebuild, exit eclipse, uninstall
  app previously on your device, load eclipse and do another clean and
  rebuild.

Comment: @JoaoBiriba I'll follow your step and I'll write you the result, thank you so much for a clear step by step guide :D

Comment: @JoaoBiriba I'm on the fourth point and when I try to add the project lib folder I can't browse for it. This is a snapshot: [link](http://i277.photobucket.com/albums/kk71/ErikaSparrow/Cattura.png)

Comment: Create a google play service project following steps in http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: Ok, I have to tick the "copy projects into workspace" ?? Sorry but I'm at really beginning with android :/

Comment: yes it's better, don't worry we are here for help :)

Comment: Ok many thanks :) - it return an Error: Resource '/HomeActivity/' already exists and in the background I see many error red lines :(

Comment: here the red lines:

[2014-09-19 10:33:36 - RealtimePlaygroundHomeActivity] /RealtimePlaygroundHomeActivity/gen already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it.

[2014-09-19 10:46:25 - google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-9'

[2014-09-19 10:46:26 - MainActivity] Unable to resolve target 'android-9'

[2014-09-19 10:46:30 - google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-9'

Comment: You can try as in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611017/importing-google-play-service-library-showing-a-red-x-next-to-this-reference-and

Comment: Ok understood @JoaoBiriba. My packages I imported don't find the path of the real imports, in fact there are a red cross...now I imported the right path but red cross near packages are still there. :/

Comment: @JoaoBiriba we have news. I go deep into javas files and I solved solvable problems that they couldn't find android.support.v4 library and maps libraries and I added manually. But now in every javas they don't find android.support.v7 and the R class.